# Dynamically added fragments are not removed when the container is removed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to understand a bad behaviour in fragments: the `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` methods are called even the fragment is not 'visible' in the layout.

If you use the code:

```
TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragmentDetail, testFragment, "test");
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.commit();
```

replacing the FrameLayout with id fragmentDetail with the fragment and then you rotate the device, the fragments method are still invoked even if the container is not present anymore in the portrait layout. This doesn't happen if you use the 'static' `<fragment>` tag. 
If you use the static fragment, the fragments methods are invoked just when the fragment appears. Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour without using the fragment tag? I need a way to avoid the rendering of the fragment if it is not in the layout.

Thanks

Comment: This question might be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164341/handling-orientation-changes-with-fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found one fix to this. It is slightly different from the suggested [Handling orientation changes with Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164341/handling-orientation-changes-with-fragments) one:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if (!fragment.isInLayout() && container == null) return null;
     ...
     }
```

In this way you can avoid the case when the fragment is statically put into the layout (in that case the container is null but the method isInLayout() returns true.
By the way it is still weird to me this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, fragments work almost as Activities. They have the same lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle So, if you don't have references to them, it won't  make them close. They are referenced by the system and live by themselves. So, you should finish them somehow.

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the fragment that doesn't appear in portrait but I don't know how.

Comment: remove the fragments via FragmentManager

Comment: popBackStack(String name, int flags)
Pop the last fragment transition from the manager's fragment back stack.

Comment: yes, the problem is when? since I want to avoid the call to onCreateView on the fragment, when should I do the removal and how? I tried to remove the fragment in onCreate of the Activity but it doesn't work and the onCreateView is still called